# I have list inside python list. I want to extract sublists based on another new list

Tags: python

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [100, 13, 17], [5, 14, 29], [17, 55, 1000]]

list_2 = [1, 100]
```

The return list should contain sublist of `list_1`, if atleast one element from `list_2` present in sublist of `list_1`

looking for results similar to `[[1, 2, 3], [100, 13, 17] ]`

If `list_2 = [5, 13, 17, 55]`:

```
[[100, 13, 17], [5, 14, 29],[17, 55, 1000]]
```

If `list_2 = [29]`:

```
[[5, 14, 29]]
```

I'm looking for a fastest way to achieve this, since most of the time, length of my `list_1` is more than 5 millions.

Is there any network library functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a way to do it:

```
list_3 = [x for x in list_1 if any(y in x for y in list_2)]
```

The "magic" happens in the `any` which loops though the elements of `list_2` and checks to make sure at least one of them exists in the sublist that is passed to the `list_3`

If you want something more *tidy* you can go with the following:

```
list_1 = [[1,2,3], [100,13,17], [5,14,29],[17,55,1000]]


def get_new_list(list_from, list_criteria):
    # if the list holding the "criteria" is big (has to be tested and calibrated), converting it to a set will speed things up.
    if len(list_criteria) > 50:  
        list_criteria = set(list_criteria)
    return [x for x in list_from if any(y in x for y in list_criteria)]

list_2 = [1,100]
print(get_new_list(list_1, list_2))  # [[1, 2, 3], [100, 13, 17]]

list_2 = [5,13,17,55]
print(get_new_list(list_1, list_2))  # [[100, 13, 17], [5, 14, 29], [17, 55, 1000]]

list_2 = [29]
print(get_new_list(list_1, list_2))  # [[5, 14, 29]]
```

As you can see, there is no need to an external library or anything else. Just good all standard Python.

Comment: Repeatedly scanning list_2 to test for membership is likely to be slower than building a set containing all elements of list_2 once, and checking membership in the set: many comparisons, scaling badly with list_2 size, instead of a single hash lookup.

Comment: @LorenzoGatti if `list_2` has many *elements* the conversion to set **does** make sense. Otherwise there is no benefit in my eyes. The *repeatedly* bit I do not understand tbh.

Comment: list_2 is scanned from the beginning for each element of a list_1 element that needs testing for list_2 membership. Work is proportional to the product of the number of elements of list_1 and list_2 rather than the number of elements of list_1.

Comment: @Kounis. Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that the length of list_1 is likely to be 5 million, but list_2 always less than 1000. will it (get_new_list ) be faster?

Comment: @BalamuruganSelvam It will, yes. Are the sublists of `list_1` longer than `list_2`?

Comment: @ Kounis. yes. len(list_1) is close to 5 million. len(list_2) <= 1000

Comment: @BalamuruganSelvam The sublists of `list_1` not `list_1` itself. That you already told me.

Comment: @Kounis. length of eachsublists of list_1 is close to 100.